# SOAPFault: soapenv:VersionMismatch Error

Tags: soapui

I gave all request as properly but I could not get response.Its Showing version mismatch error.

**Requset XML**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://test1.test.com/ticket/v1" xmlns:v3="http://test1.test.com/commonheader/v3">
               </soapenv:Header>
            <soap:Body>
                  <sit:SubmitSectorRequest>
                     <sit:RadioEquipmentType/> 
                     <sit:BBUPortNumber/> 
                     <sit:vendorName/> 
                     <sit:rrhEquipmentType/> 
                     <sit:radioSerialNumber/> 
                     <sit:radioID/> 
                     <sit:radioFMId/> 
                     <sit:ERPText>DBM</sit:ERPText> 
                     <sit:antennaHeight/> 
                     <sit:antennaTilt/> 
                     <sit:antennaType>0</sit:antennaType> 
                     <sit:effectivePower>290</sit:effectivePower> 
                     <sit:equipmentId>T179</sit:equipmentId> 
                     <sit:equipmentName>NS39 PENNINGTON BEND</sit:equipmentName> 
                     <sit:forwardPower>20</sit:forwardPower> 
                     <sit:market>DEOIT</sit:market> 
                     <sit:orientation/> 
                     <sit:region>CENTRAL</sit:region> 
                     <sit:retSiteId/> 
                     <sit:sectorId>3</sit:sectorId> 
                     <sit:sectorStatus>1</sit:sectorStatus> 
                     <sit:siteId>314179</sit:siteId> 
                     <sit:tilt/> 
                     <!--Optional:--> 
                     <sit:submitter>BA4309</sit:submitter> 
                     <!--Optional:--> 
                     <sit:SoftSectorId>TNL03179_9</sit:SoftSectorId> 
                     <!--Optional:--> 
                     <sit:remoteUSID/> 
                     <!--Optional:--> 
                     <sit:isRRHTowerMounted>0</sit:isRRHTowerMounted>
                  </sit:SubmitSectorRequest>
               </soap:Body>
            </soap:Envelope>
```

**Response XML**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
               <soapenv:Body>
                  <soapenv:Fault>
                     <faultcode>soapenv:VersionMismatch</faultcode>
                     <faultstring>Transport level information does not match with SOAP Message namespace URI</faultstring>
                     <detail/>
                  </soapenv:Fault>
               </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Please help me to fix this version mismatch error and share the solutions

Answer (score 16):

It is the issue with the "xmlns:soap" value "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 ,Instead of this you can use "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" which will solve your issue .

SOAP versioning is based on XML namespaces. SOAP 1.1 is identified by the schemas.xmlsoap.org namespace while SOAP 1.2 is identified by the second one.

Answer (score 5):

From the standard you can see [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part1/#faultcodes), in `SOAP Fault` the faultCode `VersionMismatch` must be returned when:

> The faulting node found an invalid element information item instead of the expected Envelope element information item. The namespace, local name or both did not match the Envelope element information item required by this recommendation

So the problem in your case could be the namespaces on your request are not correct, and `<soapenv:Header>` tag is not well formed, due your server is returning a `VersionMismatch` error. If you take a look on your request:

`<soapenv:Header>` is not well formed, to close and empty tag use `<soapenv:Header/>` not `</soapenv:Header>`.

And you're defining the follow namespace prefixes:

```
xmlns:v1="..." xmlns:v3="..."
```

However in your request in your elements you're using `sit` prefix when it's not defined.

Fix this problem and probably the error goes away.